# How to enable component gateway, jupyter notebook in gcp dataproc cluster, once the cluster is created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

We have the cluster created and running in gcp, we want to include the component gateway - jupyter notebook. I know that can be, if the cluster is creating for the first time. if the cluster has created, do we able to enable the component gateways by anyway?

Need a way to check, how the component gateways can be enabled, if the cluster is created and running.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, you need to re-created cluster with these features enabled.